# Gradle - Java 9 - spring-data-ja

Tags: gradle, spring-data-jpa, java-9

I try to build an already existing project with the JDK 9 and gradle.

I think I have a problem with the module loading.

Here is a sample of my gradle dependencies :

```
compile("org.springframework:spring-context:${spring_version}"){
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:${spring_data_version}"){
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}

compile ("org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:${commons_dbcp2_version}"){
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:${hibernate_version}"){
    exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction'
}

compile ("org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:${hibernate_version}"){
    exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction'
}
```

When I try to build, I get the following error when running the tests:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
```

So one solution was to also include the following dependency :

```
compile "javax.transaction:jta:1.1"
```

And the build now exits with the module duplication error like this :

```
error: module flyway.core reads package javax.transaction.xa from both jta and java.sql
error: module hibernate.jpa reads package javax.transaction.xa from both jta and java.sql
error: module hibernate.entitymanager reads package javax.transaction.xa from both jta and java.sql
```

I also tried to include the option --add-modules java.se.ee , but it still does not work.

To resume my question : I need to have the java.sql in my module-info.java but I also need the javax.transaction:jta dependency jar and this jar conflicts with the java.sql module.

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: I tried the config found on gradle doc : https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/  ,


In the build.gradle : 
    `afterEvaluate {

        compileJava {
            doFirst {
                options.compilerArgs = [
                        '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                ]
            }
        }`

Comment: Actually I tried many configurations to add the modules, I also tried this in the `build.gradle` : 

`tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {

    options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.se.ee"]
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.se.ee"]
}`

Comment: The issues doesn't state that its not able to find the module/package. It reads the package from two (possibly automatic) modules. You can exclude it from either of it keeping the other which still provides you the functionality that you need.

Comment: Did you try *not adding* `compile "javax.transaction:jta:1.1"` and just doing `"--add-modules", "java.se.ee"` when ..... *When I try to build,I get the following error when running the tests:`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`*

Comment: Yes, when I don't include the javax.transaction:jta, I get the first error : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`, even with the --add-modules java.se.ee

Comment: and then if you do `"--add-modules", "java.se.ee"` at that time, does that not solve?

Comment: If this is an existing project (compiling or testing code on the class path only) then it should work. However, you need to avoid `--add-modules java.se.ee` (or ALL-SYSTEM) as you don't want the java.transaction module to be resolved - you can't split the javax.transaction package between the class path and module. The error message "error: module flyway.core reads package javax.transaction.xa from both jta and java.sql ..." suggests that you've ended up with jta on the module path, I suspect you don't want that unless you are developing your own module.

Comment: Yes this is an existing project, divided in many sub-projects : I'm trying to turn those sub-projects into java modules and build that with gradle. But maybe this is not the right way and I should keep my project in the java8 way ?

Answer (score 1):

The issues doesn't state that its not able to find the module/package. It reads the package from two (possibly *automatic*) modules. You can exclude it from either of it keeping the other which still provides you the functionality that you need.

So currently, you can fix this by including -

```
exclude group: 'javax.transaction.xa', module: 'moduleBringingThisPackage'
```

where `'moduleBringingThisPackage'` can be found by scanning the dependency hierarchy of your module.

---

Though I am not very good at gradle, but to find the *moduleBringingThisPackage*, you can use

```
gradle dependencies
```

to list out the dependencies that are brought by your top-level dependencies and further [you can `exclude` the dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies) that adds in the `javax.transaction.xa` to them.

---

***Edit***: With the updated question, I think there is a shorter version to it.

(1) When I try to build, I get the following error when running the tests:

> `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`

(2) So one solution was to also include the following dependency :

> `compile "javax.transaction:jta:1.1"`

***Don't do the Step (2)*** from above and instead just add the

```
{ options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.se.ee"] }
```

in your `build.gradle` file at this point of time

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The problem is that the xa package is inside the javax.transaction:jta dependency, I can't exclude just the package from the jar itself.

Comment: And I also need to make the module java.sql as required in my module-info.java because I need a `javax.sql.DataSource`

Comment: @SamClarenc You shall exclude the `javax.transaction.xa` from either of the module and not both. And you need not exclude the modules but transitive dependency coming in from one your top level dependency

Comment: I'm not sure I explained my problem clearly : I need the SystemException class, which is in the javax.transaction:jta dependency jar. But, within this jar, there's a **package** javax.transaction.xa that gets conflicted with the jdk9 module java.sql . In gradle, you can exclude a child dependency but not a package within a jar. 
My main problem is that I can't find out where to manage exclusions in jdk9 modules.

Comment: @SamClarenc With module system this is restricted, you cannot use same package from different modules unless you try `--patch-modules` which is not encouraged to be used. Also could you edit the question with why you need the package from both the modules and the jar bringing the dependencies.

Comment: OK thanks. I update the question, but I keep it open, maybe we'll find a solution without the patch-modules option !

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work either, that was my first try before including the javax.transaction:jta dependency :(

Comment: At that time, I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException`

Comment: I tried to create a "fake" javax.transaction.SystemException in my project and my build now passes, but it's not a good solution indeed...